# How to click on load button dynamically using selenium python?

Tags: python, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to click on **load-more** until it disappear on that page.

I have tried but it sometimes work or giving error. It is not perfect solution which i did.

I can have **multiple url in a list** and hit one by one and **load-more** until it disappear from that page.

Thanks in advance for helping.

**Code**

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

url = ["https://www.zomato.com/HauzKhasSocial","https://www.zomato.com/ncr/wendys-sector-29-gurgaon","https://www.zomato.com/vaultcafecp"]
for load in url:
    driver.get(load)
    xpath_content='//div[@class = "load-more"]' 
    temp_xpath="true"
    while temp_xpath: 
        try:  
            #driver.implicitly.wait(15)
            #WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,xpath_content))) 
            WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,xpath_content)))
            #urls=driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath_content) 
            urls=driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath_content)
            text=urls.text
            if text:
                temp_xpath=text  
            print "XPATH=",temp_xpath  
            driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath_content).click()
            #driver.execute_script('$("div.load-more").click();')  
        except TimeoutException:
            print driver.title, "no xpath of pagination"
            temp_xpath=""
            continue
```

Most of time I get following error while running my program.

```
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 173, in execute
response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 349, in execute
return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 380, in _request
resp = self._conn.getresponse()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1045, in getresponse
response.begin()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 409, in begin
version, status, reason = self._read_status()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 373, in _read_status
raise BadStatusLine(line)
httplib.BadStatusLine: ''
```

Comment: What happens if you switch to chrome? Is it still reproducible? Thanks.

Comment: What selenium and firefox versions are you using?

Comment: I am using selenium version 2.45.0 and Firefox version 37.0.1

Comment: Good, so 2 things to try: chrome and firefox 35.0.1 (downgrade firefox).

Comment: While using  selenium 2.45.0 and firefox 35.0.1 or phantomjs giving error **Error** XPATH= LOAD MORE 19
XPATH= LOAD MORE 14
XPATH= LOAD MORE 9
XPATH= LOAD MORE 4
 raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException:  Message: Element is no longer attached to the DOM
Stacktrace:
    at fxdriver.cache.getElementAt (resource://fxdriver/modules/web-element-cache.js:8956)

Comment: **Error** **StaleElementReferenceException: Message: Element is no longer attached to the DOM Stacktrace:** while using  selenium 2.45.0 and firefox 35.0.1. Can you help me out please?

Answer (score 0):

You probably get the BadStatus error because of a bug that has been fixed in the latest versions of Selenium webdrivers. I got into a similar situation recently and here's the thread of discussion with the developers that helped me out.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1548